# How to get a side column without creating a new web part page in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-addin, list-item

[image: Need help with creating Left Column in Sharepoint 2010]

I have a list with the following columns already on it. {Date, Request, Requestor,...,...} etc and I'd like to create a left column that has certain links. As shown in the image, that column contains {Link1, Link2, Link3}. Can this be done without creating a new web part page?If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Is it a web part list, or an HTML table on a regular page?